# Is it legitimate to change a document's style by manipulating the contents of style tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a project I'm working on, I'm contemplating the idea of a sort of CSS-editor.  I'm wondering if it's "legit" to expect to see changes in the document when changing the text contents of style tags.

It seems to work on Firefox, but I'm wondering if it's ok in other browsers, and if it's generally an acceptable thing to do.

Yes, it's not an ideal way of doing things, however it may be the most efficient for what I want to do.

Comment: it should work, have you tested on ie,chrome,ff, and safari?

Comment: Nope, I don't have Safari and IE is a big hassle, so I'm asking first.

Answer (score 2):

For a CSS editor, I think it will be the best way to do it. It would be exactly the same as changing CSS. But it might require testing for other browsers. Probably it will work on Opera and Chrome as well.